# A question about the series $\frac{\arctan(x)}{e^x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I just see a demonstration on how to find the Maclaurin expansion for $\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{e^x}$

[image]

The part I don't understand I circle in red.

How does he obtains $c_0=0$?
and then $c_0+c_1=1$
then $c_1+c_2=0$

And then for the third degree, why is there an $\frac{1}{2}$ that involves here?

I am very interested in this technique of find the unknown coefficients of an unknown series based on two known series.

Comment: The author is multiplying the two series in the LHS and equating the coefficients with the series in the RHS. For example, if you compute the product in the LHS, the only independent term is $c_0$. Meanwhile, in the RHS, there is no independent term (or, the independent term is zero), so $c_0=0$. We're using the fact that two power series are equal iff their coefficients are equal.

Comment: I see, this seems to be a powerful technique. I don't understand why he gets the $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @JamesWarthington the only way to get a term of degree $3$ is $c_1x\cdot x^2/2+c_2 x^2\cdot x+c_0\cdot x^3/6=-\frac{1}{3}x^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that on the RHS, there is no constant. But on the LHS, $c_0\cdot1$ is a constant, which means $c_0=0$.

Similarly, you could see, on the RHS, the term of degree $1$ is $x$ with coefficient $1$, and on the LHS the only way to get that term is $c_1x\cdot1+c_0\cdot x=(c_1+c_0)x$. That will give us $c_1+c_0=1$.

If you do this for terms on the RHS of higher degrees, you will get a system of equations of $c_i$'s and then you will be able to solve each of them (though not 100% rigorous since this solution didn't demonstrate a general equation for the term of arbitrary degree $n$).

Comment: $c_0\cdot 1=1$, no?

Comment: Is this what is called the Cauchy product of two power series?

Comment: @JamesWarthington No. $c_0\cdot 1$ is a constant term, and the constant term on the RHS is $0$. Therefore, $c_0\cdot 1=0$

Comment: @JamesWarthington Yes it is a Cauchy product.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand.

Comment: @JamesWarthington Did you see any constant term on the RHS?

Comment: Yes, the first term $1\cdot x$

Comment: @JamesWarthington That is not a constant. That is a term of degree 1. A constant should be a fixed number.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.

Comment: @JamesWarthington Great.

Comment: @JamesWarthington You could accept the answer if you get the point! :)

Comment: Sorry, I think got mixed up again, the first term of the known series on the right hand side is 1, so how can its coefficient be 0?

Comment: @JamesWarthington The coefficient of the first term on the RHS is the coefficient of the term of degree 1. Which is actually $c_0+c_1$ on the LHS. $c_0=0$ are the constants on both sides, which equals to $c_0\cdot 1$ on the LHS and $0$ on the RHS.

Comment: can you develop this into a system of equations in your reply. I need to learn this technique badly so I can master the art of manipulating series.

Comment: @JamesWarthington You could write those two series on the LHS as two power series and then write the RHS as a power series. Then finally you will be able to manipulate those coefficients. You will get what you want after a lot of works done.

Comment: Does this video explain well the algorithm for Cauchy product? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ln_FgckN78

Comment: @JamesWarthington Yes, it does. But I won't call this an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply the series on the left you want to get the series on the right.

You count the constants on both sides, you have $(C_0)(1)$ on the left side but no constant on the right side so $C_0 =0$

Now you count how many $x$ you have on each side.

On the left side you have $(C_0+C_1)x$ and on the right side you have $x$, so $C_0+C_1 =1$ and so forth.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Can you explain to the OP why no constant on the RHS suggests $c_0\cdot 1=0$? He seems pretty confused. I couldn't give him an appropriate hint... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @James Warthington  In mathematics we have many confusing notation. for example if I  write $x$ it is understood that it is $1x$ and If I write $x$ it is $x+0$ and when I write $sqrt x$ it is the same as $x^{1}{2}$. In the case of series if teh first term is $0$ we just drop it,  so when you multiply the given series in the question we get $C_0=0$

Answer (score 0):

So I post this up as a question again:

[image]

In this series, the constant term is one and not zero, why is it the case?

Comment: The constant term, in this case, is $1$ since $1\cdot 1$ is one. Try to study polynomials products.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that
\begin{equation*}
\arctan x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}, \quad |x|<1
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{e}^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!}, \quad |x|<\infty.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\arctan x}{\operatorname{e}^{x}}
&=(\arctan x)\operatorname{e}^{-x}\\
&=\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\Biggr] \Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\Biggr]\\
&=x\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}\cos\biggl(\frac{k\pi}{2}\biggr)x^k \Biggr] \Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^k\Biggr]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{1}{\ell+1}\cos\biggl(\frac{\ell\pi}{2}\biggr) \frac{(-1)^{k-\ell}}{(k-\ell)!}\Biggr]x^{k+1}, \quad |x|<1.
\end{align*}